# Regex to match a pattern and group correct elements

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have following kind of strings

```
//ABCD E 1234 L1
//ABCD E 1234,2345 L2
//ABCD E 4567
//ABCD E 2435,4679
```

To match the above strings I wrote the patter like below.

```
Pattern.compile("//\\s*ABCD\\s+E\\s+(((\\d*,\\s*\\d*)*)|(\\d*+(((,\\s*\\d*,\\s*\\d*)*)))+)\\s*(.*?)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

All of the above Strings matches to the above pattern.
But when I try to get the numbers after ABCD E ie group(1) and to get the label ie group(8) I am getting wrong result.

//ABCD E 1234 L1 and //ABCD E 4567 gives wrong result. 
 group(1) is empty for both strings and group(8) is 1234 L1 and 4567.

I suspect (.*?) is the culprit here I guess but I am not sure what else to use.

If somebody knows a good pattern to match above strings please let me know.

P.S: Number after ABCD E are 1234, 2345, 456 etc L1 and L2 are called lables. Basically after ABCD E it could be just numbers without any lables(lables are mixture of no and charctaetrs) or both numbers and lables,

I want just the numbers and lables separately

Comment: Which numbers are you trying to extract?  Just the 1 or 2 numbers after the `E`, or do you also want the number attached to the `L`?  Does the sample input you showed us represent _all_ use cases, or are there some which you are not showing us?

Comment: I need all the numbers after E but not after L. L1 or L2 are lables. It could be any string there. Need not start with L. For ex //ABCD 1234,679 xyz. Here I need 1234,679 as one group and xyz as another

Comment: But will you always have either one or two numbers?

Comment: Nope numbers are more than one. //ABCD 1234,5678,2345,45 or //ABCD E 456,7689,687 M1X is also valid

Comment: I think a combination of splitting and regex is really the way to go here.  I also wish you would update your question showing us the full gamut of what these strings might look like.

Comment: Regex isn't a panacea for every problem, and Java's built-in string manipulation functions are also useful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
(\s*ABCD\s+E\s+)(?<num>[\d,]+)\s*(?<label>[A-Z]\d)?
```

- `(\s*ABCD\s+E\s+)` - capture obligatory part,
- `(?<num>[\d,]+)` - capture digits and commas
- `(?<label>[A-Z]\d)?` - if there is such, capture upper case letter followed by digit,

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vH7lQ7/1)

to get up to 3 captured groups, and for example split `num` group with `,` to get multiple numbers. Or you can try with:

```
(?<pre>ABCD\s*E\s*)|(?<=\G),?(?<num>\d+)|(?<=\G)\s*(?<label>[A-Z]\d)
```

- `(?<pre>ABCD\s*E\s*)` - capture combination `ABCD E`,
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\G),?(?<num>\d+)` - capture four digits, preceeded by another
  captured fragment, optionaly with comma
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\G)\s*(?<label>[A-Z]\d)` - capture upper case letter followed by
  digit, preceeedec by another captured fragment, optionaly with spaces

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kS0cK8/1)

to get just numbers and labels in different matches. However if text from which you want to extract this data contain more similar combinations, it could give more output, but it depends on rest of background text.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*(\/\/ABCD)\s+(E)\s+(\d+([,.]\d+)?)\s+([A-Z0-9]*)?

#0  //ABCD E 1234 L1
#1  //ABCD
#2  E
#3  1234
#4  null
#5  L1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use a regex to extract the comma-separated portion of the string containing the numbers, and then to split this match by comma to obtain the individual numbers you want.

```
String input = "ABCD E 456,7689,687 M1X";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*\\s([0-9,]*)\\s([^0-9].*)");
Matcher queryMatcher = pattern.matcher(input);

String csvMatch = "";
String otherMatch = "";
if (queryMatcher.find()) {
    csvMatch   = queryMatcher.group(1);
    otherMatch = queryMatcher.group(2);
}
String[] matches = csvMatch.split(",");

for (String match : matches) {
    System.out.println("Found a number: " + match);
}
System.out.println("Found other: " + otherMatch);
```

**Output:**

```
Found a number: 456
Found a number: 7689
Found a number: 687
Found other: M1X
```

You can test the regex itself at the following link:

```
[^0-9]*\\s([0-9,]*)\\s([^0-9].*)
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oS8jV4/1)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the numbers section and the label section, you can simplify the regex as this:

```
ABCD E (\d+(?:,\d+)*)(?: (\w+))?
```

**Legenda**

```
ABCD E      # matches literal string 'ABCD E ', note the empty spaces
(           # open capturing group 1
 \d+        # matches 1 or more digits
 (?:,\d+)*  # non capturing group: matches comma followed by 1 or more digits. Can be zero o more time repeated
)           # close capturing group 1
(?:         # a non capturing group
            # a literal empty space ' '
 (\w+)      # capturing group 2 composed by 1 or more of [a-zA-Z0-9_]
)?          # close the non capturing group and make it optional
```

Adding a certain flexibility (replacing spaces with a group with tabs too `[ \t]`) the above becomes:

```
ABCD[ \t]+E[ \t]+(\d+(?:,\d+)*)(?:[ \t]+(\w+))?
```

**Regex Demo**

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/oJ5tY6/2)

**Code Demo**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String ln    = System.lineSeparator();
String input = "ABCD E 1234 L1"      + ln
             + "ABCD E 1234,2345 L2" + ln
             + "ABCD E 4567"         + ln
             + "ABCD E 2435,4679"    + ln
             + "ABCD E 2435,4679,657 L6";

final Pattern labelPattern = Pattern.compile("ABCD[ \\t]+E[ \\t]+(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)(?:[ \\t]+(\\w+))?");
Matcher m = labelPattern.matcher(input);

int line = 1;
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.print("Line " + line++ + ": ");

  if ( ! m.group(2) )
    System.out.println("'" + m.group(1) + "'"); // print number section
  else
    System.out.println("'" + m.group(1) + "', '" + m.group(2)+ "'"); // print numbers and label section
}
```

**Output**

```
Line 1: '1234', 'L1'
Line 2: '1234,2345', 'L2'
Line 3: '4567'
Line 4: '2435,4679'
Line 5: '2435,4679,657', 'L6'
```